# Android - apply theme from older API

Tags: android, android-theme

I would like to deploy my app on APIs 8-17. However, for purely aesthetic reasons I would like to apply the default theme as it appears on api 8 as the theme for the app across all API levels.

For example, the older theme has an edittext that has an orangeish border around it, whereas the newer them uses a borderless blue line.

By limiting which APIs i deploy too I have been able to accomplish this but that isn't really a solution.

Does anyone know how this can be accomplished?

Thanks

**Update**

For whatever reason applying "Theme" as the theme did not force it to revert to the "Theme" theme, but instead left it as the default Holo. Using the answers below I simply called "Theme" as the parent in my custom theme (without altering any of its attributes) and set it as my application theme in the manifest. This solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `res/values` directory, you can have a `themes.xml` file with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="Theme" parent="@android:Theme">

    </style>

</resources>
```

Your app theme will now subclass from default Theme instead of `Theme.Holo` and you should be able to get older theme on newer android versions as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, maybe I was not clear enough. I would like to apply the theme that is the default theme for pre-Honeycomb API levels to those APIs above 11 as well. Essentially, I want to find out what that older default theme is, and then apply it as my theme (override the default) on all API levels.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the default theme, it will be different between the API levels. However in the styles, you can create a custom Theme, modify an existing Theme or give a different Theme to each different API of your choice.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am perfectly willing to create a custom theme but I don't know how to go about getting the theme styles I want. Is there a way I could use an older default theme as a parent? Or else is the API 8 theme stored somewhere in the android SDK files that I could copy the style info? I want to use that older default theme as my theme for the newer APIs as well.

Comment: If you know the name of the API 8 Theme, then in the styles you type: `<style name="API8Theme" parent="@android:API8Theme">` and then you customize each of its components. Check this out: http://janrain.com/blog/introduction-to-android-theme-customization/